# what is the current salesforce release

Tags: certification, release

what is current salesforce release, where can we find that information?Is there any specific release date for spring, summer and winter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, Summer '20 is in the process of being rolled out to production Salesforce orgs. This process will continue for a bit less than two weeks until all orgs are on Summer '20.

Releases are announced months in advance and publicized through a variety of media. [Here's](https://www.salesforce.com/releases/summer-20/overview) the overview for Summer '20, which also includes a link to sign up for Release Readiness emails and to the relevant [Chatter group](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001okuCAA).

You can find the exact upcoming release dates for your org by locating your instance (in Company Information in Setup), then searching for it at [trust.salesforce.com](https://trust.salesforce.com) and clicking "Maintenance". [Here](https://status.salesforce.com/instances/NA98/maintenances) is an example for the NA98 instance, showing Summer '20 release on July 10 and Winter '21 on October 9.

Comment: API version 49 too?

Comment: Yep, that's Summer '20.